# How to pass lambda function by pointer?

Tags: c++

I am a new in c++ maybe I miss something, but actually what I need to do is: I have a class that processing something in other thread, during this processing I need that it invoke a callback for progress.

How I see I can do it, I need to declarate pointer (maybe shared_ptr) for my callback function as a class member, than I have a setter in order to pass pointer to callback and then I can use it. A few issues here are how to pass it correctly? How to invoke pointer on function?

My implementation is:

```
class RobocopyCopy
{
    //Public members
public:
    typedef std::function<void(int)> TVoidIntCallback;

    RobocopyCopy * set_monitoring_done_callback(TVoidIntCallback monitoring_done_callback)
    {
       m_pMonitoring_done_callback = &monitoring_done_callback;
       return this;
    }

    //This method executes in background
    void execute()
    {
        ...
        //and here I need to invoke my callback
        (TVoidIntCallback *)m_pMonitoring_done_callback(777); //but this is not correct


private:
    TVoidIntCallback * m_pMonitoring_done_callback;


...
}
```

and final implementation of this should be like this (I think) :

```
RobocopyCopy robocopy;
    robocopy.set_monitoring_done_callback([this](int my_progress) {
        printf("Progress is :: %d", my_progress);
    });
```

So, as I mentioned above questions is :

1. how to pass this function callback as a lambda and save in `Robocopy` class as a pointer
2. How to invoke this function correctly, because this `(TVoidIntCallback *)m_pMonitoring_done_callback(777);` doesn't work.

Comment: `m_pMonitoring_done_callback` shouldn't be a pointer. Drop the star, make it `TVoidIntCallback m_pMonitoring_done_callback;` Then call it simply as `m_pMonitoring_done_callback(777);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using VC++ I hope this code will be successful for you.

```
class RobocopyCopy
{
   typedef std::function<void(int)> TVoidIntCallback;
   TVoidIntCallback evnt;
   public:

   RobocopyCopy* set_monitoring_done_callback(TVoidIntCallback 
   monitoring_done_callback)
   {
     //set callBack function from out side.
     evnt = monitoring_done_callback;
     return this;
   }

    void execute() {
       //invoke your callBack
      evnt(1000000);
    }
};

int main()
{
   RobocopyCopy obj;
   obj.set_monitoring_done_callback([](int data) {
    std::cout << data << "\n";
    })->execute();
}
```